# Angular 2 validate fields just on submit - cancel the other events for validation

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, custom-validators

I have this form on angular2 with custom validators and normal validators, My main issue is I'm not able to limit this validation just on submit, when I do a change or blur the input element, it keeps triggering. 
I been trying to override the eventChanges and trigger on and off the validation, but I think that could be another simple solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cAN you share your code so that we can see what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way, Upgrade to Angular 5.

The new implementation of the FormControl tag is  updateOn: 'blur' & updateOn: 'submit' (Angular 5 edition).

Reference in here:
http://fiyazhasan.me/angular-forms-validation-updateon-blur/